# Java JPA write only ID for nested entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I avoid unnecessary queries to the DB?
I have LoadEntity with two nested entity - CarrierEntity and DriverEntity. Java class:

```
@Entity
public class LoadEntity {
  ...
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="carrier_id", nullable=false)
  private CarrierEntity carrierEntity;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="driver_id", nullable=false)
  private DriverEntity driverEntity;
}
```

But API send me **carrierId** and **driverId**. I make it:

```
DriverEntity driverEntity = driverService.getDriverEntityById(request.getDriverId());
loadEntity.setDriverEntity(driverEntity);
loadRepository.save(loadEntity);
```

How can I write only driverId with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Data JPA you can always fall back on plain SQL.
Of course, this will side step all the great/annoying logic JPA gives you.
This means you won't get any events and the entities in memory might be out of sync with the database.
For this reason you might also increase the version column, if you are using optimistic locking.

That said you could update a sing field like this:

```java
interface LoadRepository extends CrudRepository<LoadEntity, Long> {

    @Query(query="update load_entity set driver_id = :driverId where carrier_id=:carrier_id", nativeQuery=true)
    @Modifying
    void updateDriverId(Long carrierId, Long driverId);

}
```

If you just want to avoid the loading of the `DriverEntity` you may also use [`JpaRepository.getById`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I can use @Query like it. Now I have about 12 parameters in LoadEntity and must write all its in query. I hope JPA have any way, some it `loadEntity.driverEntity.id = driverId` Will be very sad write so long SQL if have not any way.

Comment: I gave you two solutions of to your original question, one of which also works for the problem stated in you comment.

Comment: JpaRepository.getById is good solution for me. Thanks